# How to add click event on django-chatit chart

Tags: django, highcharts, chartist.js

I have created a chart using django-chartit library.
Once the chart it shown, I want a click action on my chart, upon which 
chart get enlarge. How can I do this.

Moreover: it there any tutorial available to customize django-chartit charts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I read on GitHub page of the project (https://github.com/chartit/django-chartit), Highcharts v2.1.7 and v2.2.0 are known to work well with django-chartit, so you can add click event (`chart.events.click`) inside chart options object.

API Reference:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.click
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Chart.setSize

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/umckr21p/